# Query results substring to table

Tags: grafana, splunk

We have connected to our Splunk data source for logs in Grafana labs using Splunk plugin. My query returns a full log statement in this pattern under _raw as

```
INFO::[ThreadName] Updated eventId:123 to X
```

What I want to achieve is getting that eventId's into a table format in the Grafana dashboard. I used filter by name to display the _raw field. But I don't want the entire string I want only those eventId's(substring) populated in the table. I tried regex patterns but still no luck.

Please advise

I modified the query to include regex pattern. But still, it returned the entire string.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is recommended not to write "I've tried but nothing worked", but rather provide your best attempt, and ask why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

When onboarding a new sourcetype, it is best practise to create new field extractions. Splunk has plenty of documentation on this but I would start [here](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.4/Knowledge/Managesearch-timefieldextractions).

The goal is to normalize your data and enable your users to search across it in a consistent manner without having to manually extract fields every time.

That being said, if that isn't appropriate for this use case and you still want to use a search command to extract the eventId, then the following command should work based off your sample data:

```
| rex "eventId:(?<eventId>\d+)"
```